# Finding the limits to minus and plus infinity

Tags: calculus, limits

I need to calculate the $\lim_{x\to-\infty}$ and $\lim_{x\to+\infty}$ of the function:

$$f(x)=\begin{cases} \dfrac{x^2-3x^3e^{2x}}{x^4+3},x<1 \\ \dfrac{3x^2+\cos(3x+1)}{x^2+2},x≥1 \end{cases}$$

I've attempted to use my knowledge that $-1\le \cos(x)\le1$ to conclude that:

$$\dfrac{3x^2-1}{x^2+2}\le\dfrac{3x^2+\cos(3x+1)}{x^2+2}\le\dfrac{3x^2+1}{x^2+2}$$

And since the second case should only be interested in positive values, then I've also conclude that:

$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}\dfrac{3x^2+1}{x^2+2} = 3 \Rightarrow \lim_{x\to+\infty} f(x) = 3$$

Not sure if I'm correct on this second case, so if you find my thought process incorrect I'm all ears.

As for the first case, I'm completely lost and would really appreciate some hints on the best way to approach this.

Comment: I have corrected your formulas (the exponents weren't exponents...). Please check.

Comment: thanks for that edit @JeanMarie

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about applying the same type of approach as you did for the second part. Since $e^{2x}$ is an increasing function, you have $$0<e^{2x}<e^2$$
Can you take it from here?